# Why does sed only work on direct output from echo?

Tags: bash, regex, grep, sed

I have a shell command to get the UI drawing time for an Android app (which is not really relevant to this question) in milliseconds. At any rate, the output looks like

```
I/ActivityManager( 1843): Fully drawn com.amazon.android.calypso/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: [time]
```

Where *[time]* is of the format `+###ms` or `+#s###ms` (again, not relevant here).

The command is as follows:

```
adb logcat -d | grep 'Fully drawn' | sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'
```

It works as expected when I use `echo` to directly display the output:

```
$ echo 'I/ActivityManager( 1843): Fully drawn com.amazon.android.calypso/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +233ms' | sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'
> 233

$ echo 'I/ActivityManager( 1843): Fully drawn com.amazon.android.calypso/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +1s233ms' | sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'
> 1233
```

However, when I use it on other commands that should display an output of the same format, `sed` matches the whole line rather than just the rendering time:

```
$ adb logcat -d | grep 'Fully drawn' | sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'
> I/ActivityManager( 1843): Fully drawn com.amazon.android.calypo/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +233ms
```

The same happens when I put the output into a variable first.

```
$ out="$(adb logcat -d | grep 'Fully drawn')"                                           
$ echo $out | sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'
> I/ActivityManager( 1843): Fully drawn com.amazon.android.calypo/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +233ms
```

Tried dumping the output into a text file, no dice:

```
adb logcat -d | grep 'Fully drawn' > temp.txt
cat temp.txt | sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'
> I/ActivityManager( 1843): Fully drawn com.amazon.android.calypo/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +233ms
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: adb may produce dos-like CR/LF at the end of lines. Try to skip the trailing `$` in sed command.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the cause. I changed the `ms$` to `ms.*$`, and that solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @IporSircer Perhaps do a write up as answer so the OP can close thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adb produces dos-like CR/LF at the end of lines. Try to skip the trailing `$` in sed command.